# How do I find out the type of a class instance template?

Tags: c++

I needed to find out the type of class template.

```
m_class <int> temp{};
```

Is it possible to understand that it has an 'int' or any other type ?
I tried

```
decltype( temp)
```

But it returns

```
m_clas<int>
```

I will be glad of your help.

Comment: The simplest way to achieve this would be for `m_class` to define it's template parameter as a typedef. Can you work with the `m_class` code?

Comment: @john yes (filling the response space)

Answer (score 3):

If you can modify `m_class` you can add an alias:

```
template <typename T>
struct m_class {
    using type = T;
};
```

If not you can write a type trait:

```
template <typename T>
struct m_class_type;

template <typename T>
struct m_class_type<m_class<T>> {
    using type = T;
};
```

Example:

```
int main() {
  m_class<int>::type f;
  m_class_type<m_class<int>> g;
}
```

`f` and `g` are both `int`.

Answer (score 1):

If you made `m_class` yourself, you have to keep track of T yourself:

```
    template <class T>
    class m_class {
    public:
        using type_t = T;
    };

    //...

    m_class<int>::type_t myInt = 42;
```

STL containers usually keep the element type info this way, e.g. `std::vector<int>::value_type`.